# How to send AT command using flutter_blue package in Flutter

Tags: flutter, at-command

I have searched lot of things about AT command in flutter but found nothing that work.

I have tried flutter_blue but it write characteristic not as AT command. I tried other stackoverflow solutions to convert characteristics to At command but nothing works.

Comment: In order to send AT commands you need a serial connection of some sort, so from my brief investigation it seems that flutter_blue is not capable of that and that you need to use something like flutter_bluetooth_serial instead.